# Hopfield neural network for optimization

Tags: optimization, neural-network, scheduling

could anyone recommend good article, or give some hint abut solving: "Uni-processor scheduling problem of the criterion
minimizing the weighted sum of the delays of tasks" with Hopfield neural network. I started to designing it using Hopfield and Tank approach to solve this scheduling problem( like TSP). But I encountered problem with provideing the correct energy formula and correct weight adjustment formula. J.J Hopfield an Tank use a typical TSP variables in their work and i have no good idea how to change it to match my problem requirements. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i found all necessary information in the paper written by **Alexandre de Sousa Mendes** and **Luiz Manoel Aguilera** title : **A Hopfiled neural network approach to the single machine scheduling problem** . You can find there all informations that are required to properly design a neural network to optimize scheduling problem( modifications with are needed to implement to energy formulas and some other hints).